# in Arcmap can I save a graphic line pointer within annotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation

I have an annotation layer for street names but some of the streets are very short and the annotation has been moved aside to reveal the underlying road, then on maps I draw a graphic line arrow pointing from the annotation text to the street.

Is there a way to save this line within the annotation so that I don't have to remember to draw it in on every map where i show street names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Add your annotation layer into your map and start editing (selecting your annotation source if required).

Now from the Draw toolbar, select Drawing > Active Annotation Target > [Name of Annotation Layer]

[image]

This will record any graphic elements you create into your annotation layer, rather than as elements in your map document.

Now you can draw your lines or any other graphics into your annotation layer

[image]

[image]

Remember to Save Edits when you are done, as you are creating features into your layer.

[image]